# How to Simulate Pure-Jump Process associated Marked Point Process in R

Tags: poisson-distribution, simulation, monte-carlo, poisson-process, point-process

Fix $M>0$ and let $(\tau_i,\zeta_i)_{i =1}^{\infty}$ be a [marked point process](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MarkedPointProcess.html) associated to the [poisson-random measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_random_measure) $\mu$ on $[0,1]\times [-M,M]^2\times [0,M]\times [-M,M]$ with [uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) finite-[intensity measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensity_measure) thereon.

How can we simulate (in R) the [pure jump process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609363/what-is-a-pure-jump-process) $I_t$ defined by
$$
I_t\triangleq \zeta_i \qquad \tau_i\leq t<\tau_{i+1}?
$$